# python 2.7: no module named configparser

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to run `db_create.py` in Flask, and am getting the following error:

```
from six.moves.configparser import ConfigParser
ImportError: No module named configparser
```

Even after a successfull `pip install`, the same error code comes up.

I'm seeing solutions targeting Python 3, but not lower.

Comment: In Python<3 the `configparser` module is called `ConfigParser` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#module-ConfigParser)) so I'm guessing the crux of the problem is the db_create.py script is meant only to work with Python3.  Can you share where you are getting that script from?

Comment: also, FWIW I ran `pip install six` in my py2.7 installation and then in my python-2.7 shell, I'm able to run: `from six.moves.configparser import ConfigParser`

Comment: Six is installed, and the configparser package is installed as well, but when I try your suggestion, it tells me that there's no module named configparser

Comment: And, in the shell, print configparser.__file__ gives me the following path:  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/configparser.pyc, which is what is expected.

Comment: hmm... actually I'd expect it to be the camelcase *ConfigParser* for py2.7, e.g. for me it's '/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.pyc'.  Did you `pip install ConfigParser`?

Comment: I did.  And now this is weird - the six.__file__  and ConfigParser.__file__ are in the same packages folder ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python'), while the configparser is in a different folder: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/configparser.pyc'.  However, the ImportError is over configparser - not camelcased.

Comment: ah ok, I see where the error is happening now.  It's very weird, because the `six.moves` should dynamically create a descriptor for configparser pointing to ConfigParser when run in python2.7.  Can you post the results of `python -c "import six; print six.PY2; print [(a.name,a.mod) for a in six._moved_attributes if a.name=='configparser']"`?

Comment: This is the result:  [('configparser', 'ConfigParser')]

Comment: okay then, now try:  `python -c "import six; mod = [a for a in six._moved_attributes if a.name=='configparser'][0]; print mod._resolve()"`

Comment: Are the quotes necessary? I'm getting an invalid syntax with them. Also, thanks so much for your time on this.

Comment: yep, they are if you are trying to run this from the command line.  You could do the same thing in an interactive python session without the outermost quotes

Comment: Result:  <module 'ConfigParser' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.pyc'>

Comment: hmm...that seems right. And you're sure `python -c "import six; print six.moves.configparser"` definitely does not work? Can you post the whole traceback you get?

Comment: Result (this time from command line): <module 'ConfigParser' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.pyc'>

Comment: oh... so then what happens if you run `python -c "from six.moves.configparser import ConfigParser; print ConfigParser"`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named configparser

Comment: very befuddling... okay, try: `python -c "import six.moves.configparser; print(dir(six.moves.configparser))"`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named configparser

Comment: oh wait a sec, are you running this from a directory that has a six/moves/ structure by any chance?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.  I'm just running Flask, afaik, with the standard structure.

Comment: okay, last try: `python -c "import six; print dir(six.moves)"`

Comment: ['__doc__', '__name__']

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84410/discussion-between-lemonhead-and-fstopzero).

Comment: Well, for whatever reason when I just scrapped it and started over, everything works.  Who knows what that strange error was. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone following along, this was likely caused by an old (broken) version of the `six` module, e.g. see https://github.com/Parsely/streamparse/issues/113, for instance

which caused `six.moves` to be almost empty (contained no `configparser` module)

The fix was to upgrade the version of `six` used.

Answer (score 4):

I am using CENTOS RHEL 7 with Python 2.7.5 & pip version 8.1.2 and and fixed it doing:

```
cd /home/user/
sudo pip install configparser
```

And it was done for me.
But
Previously i had installed:

```
cd /home/user/
pip install --user pytz requests tqdm tzlocal python-dateutil
```

No problems at all.

to know your python version and to know configparser check up:

```
python --version

python -c 'import six; print(six.__version__)'

python -c 'import six.moves; print(dir(six.moves))'
```

I had configparser installed previously but I was not working so I think you must install all the dependencies and libs of python pip on your `/home/user_directory`