# Trying to create Python distribution app for OSX and Windows, having difficulty with Imported libraries

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.4, py2exe, py2app

I have created a simple python gui app using Tkinter (tested on python v2 and v3) and am trying to use py2app and py2exe to distribute it.

I need the following libraries:

- boto3  (local copy downloaded to root folder)
- decimal
- json
- requests
- Tkinter (Tkinter for v2, tkinter for v3. Used `try... except ImportError:...` to get proper one)
- hashlib
- time

And I have 3 modules I've written:

- NVConnectApp.py
- NVServer.py
- DroneLogbookServer.py

My setup.py currently looks like this using help from [this tutorial](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/examples.html):

```python
'''
py2app/py2exe build script for NVConnectApp.

Will automatically ensure that all build prerequisites are available
via ez_setup

Usage (Mac OS X):
python setup.py py2app

Usage (Windows):
python setup.py py2exe
'''

import ez_setup
ez_setup.use_setuptools()

import sys
from setuptools import setup

mainscript = 'NVConnectApp.py'

if sys.platform == 'darwin':
    extra_options = dict(
        setup_requires=['py2app'],
        app = [mainscript],
        # Cross-platform applications generally expect sys.argv to
        # be used for opening files.
        options=dict(py2app=dict(argv_emulation=True)),
        # Packages
        packages=['boto3'],
        # Modules
        py_modules = ['DroneLogbookServer', 'NVServer']
     )
elif sys.platform == 'win32':
    extra_options = dict(
        setup_requires=['py2exe'],
        app=[mainscript],
        # Packages
        packages=['boto3'],
        # Modules
        py_modules = ['DroneLogbookServer', 'NVServer']
    )
else:
    extra_options = dict(
        # Normally unix-like platforms will use "setup.py install"
        # and install the main script as such
        scripts=[mainscript],
    )

setup(
    name="NVConnectApp",
    **extra_options
)
```

OSX (python 2.7.8):

I am getting errors when opening py2app's .app for OSX. The error has to do with [Boto3's configparser that's been solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662194/python-2-7-no-module-named-configparser). The error doesn't occur when I run the program from the raw script though.

Windows (python 3.4.3):

When running `python setup py2exe` I get an error that says `error: invalid command 'py2exe'`. A little research says because I didn't import py2exe in Setup.py, but after importing it (after importing setup) I get the following:

```
  3 missing Modules
  ------------------
? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
? win32api                            imported from platform
? win32con                            imported from platform
Building shared code archive 'dist\library.zip'.
```

and no .exe is generated.

What is wrong with my Setup.py?